# Interesting integral from admissions to "Scuola Normale Superiore" in Italy

Tags: proof-verification, definite-integrals

Here's a cute integral I stumbled upon today:

$$I(\alpha,\beta)=\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi \int_0^{\infty}d\rho\: \frac{\alpha\rho\cos(\beta+\rho\cos\phi)}{(\alpha^2+\rho^2)^{3/2}}$$

$$\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}$$

My calculation yields (if I haven't made any mistakes):

$$I(\alpha,\beta)=\frac{2\pi \alpha}{|\alpha|}e^{-|\alpha|}\cos \beta$$

Anybody care to provide a proof? My method involved passing from polar coordinates to cartesian coordinates and integrating using contour integration. I'd like to see different strategies (primarily to check my result, and to see if there's a particularly clever approach).

EDIT: I redid the calculations and corrected the result.

Comment: If this question is intended to belong to the "proof-checking" tag, a proof is missing. It is *Scuola Normale Superiore* with capital letters, by the way.

Comment: Switching the order of integration, then integrating by parts, and substituting $\rho=ar$, this is ultimately equivalent to showing that $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{J_1(ar)}{\sqrt{1+r^2}}~dr~=~\frac{1-e^{-a}}a,$ where *J* is the [Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function).

Comment: @Jack: corrected and added the tag.

Comment: Since $I(\alpha,\beta)$ clearly is odd in $\alpha$, the correct $I$ is probably $I(\alpha,\beta)=\frac{2\pi}{\alpha}e^{-|\alpha|}\cos \beta$. It could also be discussed what happens for $\alpha=0$. You write below in a comment that the integral diverges. But one could also view it as the integrand being constant zero, so $I(0,\beta)=0$.

Comment: You're perfectly right on the modulus, I forgot it while doing contour integration. I also suppose one could see the integral being constant $0$, but if it is doable for every $\alpha$ different from $0$ then I'd tend to say the integral diverges.